# Microsoft Sync Framework 2.1 Invalid Column Name Error

Tags: sql-server, microsoft-sync-framework

I have developed an application to sync mssql database. It was working properly until my server database schema changed. after that i am having **"Invalid Column Name"** SqlException error.
If i delete both client and server database than sync application works properly.

So please guide me to solve this issue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Sync Framework doesn't handle schema changes automatically. if you used the GetDescriptionForTable to provision, it takes the column definition at that point in time. if you alter the schema, then the scope definition is out of sync with the actual table schema.

Answer (score 0):

You have to deprovision your database and provision it again with the new schema.